# Installing Google AppEngine Blobstore library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-platform, blobstore

I'm trying to open an old project in Eclipse Oxygen. The Google Cloud Platform plugin is installed and working.

[image]

My old project references the old blobstore libraries.

The problem is that the project doesn't compile anymore because it's missing the libraries for blobstore.

[image]

I looked in Build Path > Add Libraries, but only see the new GCP libs:

[image]

Where can I find these libraries and how to install them in my project in Eclipse?

Comment: That you're not seeing the App Engine libraries in that dialog suggests that your project is not configured as an App Engine Standard project.  You should be able to right-click on the project and select _Configure > Convert to App Engine Standard Project_.

Comment: @BriandeAlwis this was the solution. Thanks! Can you make this you answer, then I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BriandeAlwis provided the answer. I'm posting it here as the answer since he only posted this in a comment.

> That you're not seeing the App Engine libraries in that dialog suggests that your project is not configured as an App Engine Standard project. You should be able to right-click on the project and select Configure > Convert to App Engine Standard Project.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
//........
```

the blobstore libraries are located in `com.google.appengine.api.*`

So what you should choose is the **App Engine API** and click finish:

[image]

In the image, I am using the `Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.7.0.201805302000`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Got this dialog after converting the project to App Engine Standard as suggested by @BriandeAlwis

Comment: I am glad you found it useful. It's up to you to upvote it :-)

Comment: Hello @DavedeJong, if this worked, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), for future reference of the community.

Comment: Actually @BriandeAlwis supplied the right answers, but in a comment, so I can't mark it as the answer.

Comment: @DavedeJong If the other user doesn't answer, you can edit this answer, to include the other bit, or post everything yourself and approve it.

Answer (score 1):

That you're not seeing the App Engine libraries in that dialog suggests that your project is not configured as an App Engine Standard project. You should be able to right-click on the project and select *Configure > Convert to App Engine Standard Project*.

After this, you should be able to add the libraries in here, choosing App Engine API and clicking finish:

[image: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.7.0.201805302000]